# represent some set to a functional form show example

Tags: real-analysis

Let say we have a set k $\subset R$

K = [a,b) for convenient  k = $[0,\infty)$,

How do we represent some function such as $f:K \to R$

can we represent f:k   like y= ..... ??

or we can only represent the some function f:k to a subset.

sorry for little confuse of the question. but i'm also confuse that my question is valid or 
not